# Does LKH perform best with $\mathrm{1\unicode{x2013}trees}$

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, heuristics

The LKH heuristic essentially generates sequence connected graphs with $n$ edges by means calculating minimum-weight spanning trees of $n-1$ of the vertices and connects the unspanned vertex to the tree via two edges of minimal weightsum; now vertex weights are determined that, when added to the weights of adjent edges, will balance vertex-degrees of the next $\mathrm{1\unicode{x2013}tree}$

> **Question:**
>
> As the vertex weights are calculated from the vertex-degrees of connected graphs with $n$ vertices and edges and because $\mathrm{1\unicode{x2013}trees}$ are not the only such graphs, have different  graphs already been evaluated regarding the quality of the tours generated via vertex-weights calculated from them?

As **an example** for an alternative strategy for planar euclidean TSPs the following could be envisaged:

- calculate the edges of the convex hull in a preprocessing step and set their weight to $0$
- repeat until a tour is found:

  - calculate the minimum weight spanning tree
  - determine the balancing vertex-weights
  - add the vertex weights to adjacent edges that do *not* belong to the convex hull

Comment: This sounds like the Held-Karp lower bound rather than the LKH heuristic.

Comment: @RobPratt I viewed it more from the angle of actually calculating an approximation of the optimal tour.